# In the triangle $ABC AN$ is the bisector of the angle $A, N \in BC$. Express the vector $AN$ in terms of the vectors $b = AC$ and $c = AB$

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $ABC$, $\vec {AN}$ is the bisector of the angle $A, N \in \vec{BC}$.

Express the vector $\vec{AN}$ in terms of the vectors $\vec b= \vec{AC}$ and $\vec C=\vec{AB}$.

**where I made a mistake?**

**Picture 1:**

[image]

I don't understand how to complete this task correctly.

In the second photo, the vectors are folded in the middle. but why do I have an incorrect answer in my task? what should the solution look like? After all, we also add two vectors.

**Picture 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is wrong. It's true only if $N$ is a mid-point of $BC$, which is not always so.

A right solution.

Let $|\vec{b}|=b$ and $|\vec{c}|=c$.

Thus, since $$\frac{BN}{NC}=\frac{AB}{AC},$$ we obtain: $$\vec{AN}=\vec{c}+\vec{BN}=\vec{c}+\frac{c}{b+c}(\vec{b}-\vec{c})=\frac{c}{b+c}\vec{b}+\frac{b}{b+c}\vec{c}.$$